# re-coding elements of multidimensional array in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Is there an efficient way to re-code elements of a multidimensional array in Matlab without having to re-code each element one by one?

```
m=[1,2,0;3,4,0]
m(:,:,2)=[2,0,1;0,4,3]

r = [11,22,33,44]
```

For example how can I re-code the nonzero elements of `m` using the values in `r` (ie `1=11`, `2=22`, `3=33` and `4=44`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> m(m~=0) = r(nonzeros(m))
m =

ans(:,:,1) =

   11   22    0
   33   44    0

ans(:,:,2) =

   22    0   11
    0   44   33
```

Explanation:

`(m~=0)` gives us logical indices (the same shape as `m`) that determine which elements in `m` to assign to:

```
>> m~=0
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =

  1  1  0
  1  1  0

ans(:,:,2) =

  1  0  1
  0  1  1
```

`nonzeros(m)` gives us the nonzero elements of `m`, to be used as indices in `r`, in the same order that they will be assigned to the left-hand side:

```
>> nonzeros(m)
ans =

   1
   3
   2
   4
   2
   4
   1
   3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be quite easy using the `:` operator, see the following code. Assumption: The values in `m` always correspond to the indices in `r`. I slightly modified the example input, so that you see, that values, that don't have a corresponding index in `r`, most likely `m(i) > numel(r)`, are omitted.

```matlab
% Slightly modified input.
m = [1, 2, 0; 3, 4, 0];
m(:, :, 2) = [2, 0, 1; 0, 5, 3]

% Recode vector.
r = [11, 22, 33, 44];

% Get indices in m which correspond to recode elements.
idx = ((m(:) > 0) & (m(:) <= numel(r)));

% Recode elements in m.
m(idx) = r(m(idx))
```

Output:

```matlab
m =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   2   0
   3   4   0

ans(:,:,2) =

   2   0   1
   0   5   3

m =

ans(:,:,1) =

   11   22    0
   33   44    0

ans(:,:,2) =

   22    0   11
    0    5   33
```